# I created a custom error page using htaccess but it doesn't work on IE?

Tags: internet-explorer, .htaccess

Am using .htaccess to create custom error pages, but the thing is that, it works  on other browsers such as safari, chrome, firefox, opera but not on IE. here's my code, what is it that am missing why won't it work on IE?

```
      ###################################
      ##
      ## HTACCESS CONTROL MODULE
      ## USED TO REDIRECT/DYNAMICALLY
      ## CONTROL URL's ON A WEBSITE
      ## 
      ##
      ###################################
       Options +FollowSymlinks
       RewriteEngine on
       RewriteRule ^(.*)\.htm$ $1.php [NC]
       # custom error documents

       ErrorDocument 404 /404.php
       ErrorDocument 403 /403.php
       ErrorDocument 500 /500.php
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

First of all this behavior can be triggered by this IE (IE8 in my case) setting:

[image]

Second, this setting will be ignored in case your error page is **larger than 512 bytes**. I.e., your error page should be larger than 512 bytes if you want it to show up in Internet Explorer.

Comment: Is there another way to automatically get the error page if that page doesn't exist in IE than doing this?

Comment: there must be something, because going to something like http://www.google.com/aaaaa in IE8 will display their custom error message, playing with headers could help I guess

Comment: i finally worked a way round it, thanks for the insight i tried that on the error pages, it didn't work because they're already more than 1kb so i simply just made the htaccess file larger than 512 bytes by adding a lot of comments on it...now it works on IE. Thanks...

Comment: Hell no! You saved me a lot of time with the sentence larger than 512 bytes. I only had a redirect which didn't work in IE9. now I know why. Adding some useless content resolves the problem! thanks